# kafka streams - rich mappers

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

**question**: I have records in a kafka topic that need to be *augmented* with metadata from a MySQL database (among others). Using Flink, it is possible to implement *rich mappers*, so a connection can be reused for multiple records.

Is there a similar functionality in *kafka streams* (java) ?

---

**random thoughts**: so far, I found the following variants:

- *mappers (lambda)*: a new instance is created for each record...
- *transformers/processors*: used for stateful operations (great!), but also means using state stores (which is not required in my use case)

Something I missed ?

*Note*: I also thought about *kafka-connect*, but I need to transform data between two kafka topics, not between external systems...

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what Matthias J. Sax said in his answer:  `Processor` and `Transformer` can be stateless or stateful.

For reference, let me also point you to the following snippets in Confluent's documentation of the Kafka Streams API (intro at http://docs.confluent.io/3.2.0/streams/developer-guide.html#processor-api)

> The Processor API can be used to implement both **stateless** as well as **stateful** operations, where the latter is achieved through the use of state stores.

There's also a demo application that implements a stateless `Transformer`:
https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/3.2.x/kafka-streams/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/MixAndMatchLambdaIntegrationTest.java

The example above (branch `3.2.x` of [confluentinc/examples](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples)) is for Confluent 3.2.0 with Apache Kafka 0.10.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transfrom()/process()` also without a state -- the state is optional. Thus, this should give you what you need.